# $ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^2}{(1+x \sin x)^2}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^2}{(1+x \sin x)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
I got $$2I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^2}{(1+x \sin x)^2}\,\mathrm dx + \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^2}{(1 - x\cos x + \sin x)^2}\,\mathrm dx $$
After this step I got stuck...

According to me I tried $\cos x=t$ put I failed.

Is this the way to solve or have some different method?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks and if you need more details I will help

Comment: Integrals of the form $\int R(x,\sin x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ (as well as $\int R(x,\cos x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int R(x,e^x)\,\mathrm{d}x$) for rational functions $R(x,y)$ are notorious for their non-integrability in elementary terms (in general sense). Do you have any particular reason to believe that this integral has an elementary closed-form?

Comment: How did you get $2I$?