# Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{x}{1+x\sin x}\right)^2 \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I used series and substitution and Feynman trick but they didn't work. Do you have any ideas?
$$\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{x}{1+x\sin x}\right)^2 \mathrm{d}x$$
I could simplify it like this:
$$\overset{/x^2}{\rightarrow} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{x}+\sin x)^2} \mathrm{d} x $$ and I used different substitutions but I failed. For example I supposed $x=\frac{1}{u}$, $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$.
Then I got stuck. And I tried these forms:
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x^a}{(1+x\sin x)^2} \mathrm{d} x,\\
I(a)= \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x^2}{(1+x\sin ax)^2} \mathrm{d} x,$$
but they did not work.

Comment: Please do not repost the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4667680/evaluating-int-0-pi-left-fracx1x-sin-x-right2-mathrmdx) with the same lack of context and own effort that caused it to be closed the first time around.

Comment: @dxiv the link you posted is broken.

Comment: @Snared The link works for 10k+ rep users. The OP deleted their question after it was closed, and deleted questions are only [visible](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) to 10k+ rep users.

Comment: Sure man, I'm not going to believe you just because you said so lol. The OP's post seems fine, it looks like they tried a few integrating techniques so far. It's a tough question, I put some thought into it. If the answer is clean I would upvote the Question but I'm afraid the answer is just gonna be some non elementary transcendental.

Comment: @Snared I can confirm dxiv's link works and has the claimed contents. And (no surprise) unfortunately Wolfram Alpha can't give this integral a closed form.

Comment: @J.G.. There is a very good approximation of the antiderivative

Comment: I have a good approximation but you did not show any work

Comment: I just need a hint to start. I am confused

Comment: @Snared Maybe you should not be so blissfully dismissive. Click the link in my previous comment and read MSE's page on "*moderation privilege awarded at 10,000 reputation*", specifically the "*viewing deleted posts*" part.

Comment: Same question, unanswered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175648. Variation: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1132865p5272843

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i edited my post. that was my first question in math.stackexchange. can  you share your approximation?thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer.*

Using my favored $1,400^=$ years old approximation of the sine function
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq x\leq\pi$$ So
$$\frac x{1+x \sin(x)}\simeq -\frac {x(x-a)(x-b)}{4(x-c)(x-d)(x-e )}$$
$(a,b)$ being the simple complex roots of
$$5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x=0$$ and $(c,d,e)$ the roots of the cubic
$$16 x^3-4(4 \pi+1 ) x^2+4 \pi  x-5 \pi^2=0$$ which we know explicitly (the real root being computed using the hyperbolic solution).

Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac {x(x-a)(x-b)}{(x-c)(x-d)(x-e )}=1+\frac C{x-c}+\frac D{x-d}+\frac E{x-e}$$

Squaring and expanding, we have simple integrands; integration leads to three rational fractions plus three logarithms.

Using the bounds and converting the more than nasty coefficient to decimals, we end with a value of $2.84409$ while numerical integration leads to $2.85065$ (relative error : $0.23$%).

Comment: thank you so much sir.